# Remove character from URI in nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I want to be able to add a single character to a URI and redirect it to a differnt url, the cam= part will be dynamic to a certain degree, as in the number after the = will change. Example below:

http:localhost:8080/jpeg?=cam1

to

http:somehost/mjpeg?=cam1

Any answers would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Glad, you can make use of exact paths in NGINX.

[image: Extract from digitalocen article]

Comment: I need to be able to remove the port and add the "m" to the uri, will this help me do it?

Comment: You can proxy_pass http:somehost/mjpeg?=cam1 

and make use of **rewrite** function, if required.